# Write a function that accepts a number n as an input, and it returns n rows that look like the following pattern. Run your function for n = 21

Tags: python, for

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

The output below is for n = 21 and n = 12

Comment: Во-первых, вопрос должен быть на русском языке. Во-вторых, это простое домашнее задание которое нужно постараться выполнить самостоятельно и приходить с конкретными вопросами